# How can i substitute javascript from parenttheme with one from childtheme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, overriding

I am trying to substitute 1 javascript file from the parent theme.
I am using the child theme of this theme and i modified 1 *.js file

When i load the file in the parent theme directory all is fine
When i load the file from the child theme all it does is finding the file in the parent theme

I tried different codes found here and on the internet but all failed

I tried

```
/*
 * Use any number above 10 for priority as the default is 10 
 * any number after 10 will load after
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts', 100 );
function my_custom_scripts()
{
    wp_dequeue_script( 'Theme-custom' );
    #wp_deregister_script( 'Theme-custom' );
    // Now the parent script is completely removed

    /*
     * Now enqueue you child js file, no need to register if you are not 
     * doing conditional loading
     */
    wp_register_script( 'Theme-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Theme-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );
    //Now we have done it correctly
}
```

and i tried

```
// dequeue your required script file
function your_child_theme_js_file_dequeue() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'Theme-custom' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'your_child_theme_js_file_dequeue', 1 );

// enqueue your required script file

function your_child_theme_js_file_override(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Theme-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_child_theme_js_file_override');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Theme-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
```

and i tried

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse26822_script_fix', 20120207);
function wpse26822_script_fix()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('Theme-custom');
    wp_enqueue_script('Theme-custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'),20151110,true);
}
```

I tried even more but will not post

I just want the child theme to load this JS file instead of the original one that comes with the theme
the Handle should stay the same as other files in the theme will also look for this js file

The parent theme registers the JS file like this

```
wp_register_script('theme-custom', trailing(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'js/custom.js', array('jquery', 'theme-dd', 'type'), false, true);
```

Comment: I can succesfully deregister the *.js file but WP is not registering and enqueuing the new file 
i used the same name for the script (as well as the filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it myself
Just forgot to register the script correct
See code below

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts', 100 );
function my_custom_scripts()
{
    wp_dequeue_script( 'custom.js' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'custom.js' );
    // Now the parent script is completely removed

    /*
     * Now enqueue you child js file, no need to register if you are not 
     * doing conditional loading
     */
    wp_register_script( 'Theme-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery', 'theme-dd', 'type'), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Theme-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );
    //Now we have done it correctly
}
```